# Need all MySQL rows with dates in the next 7 days, but the date column is not formatted normally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a column in my database 'scheduledDate', I need all rows in the database that have a scheduledDate within 7 days from today.

I could use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE `scheduledDate` > DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

The only problem is, the 'scheduledDate' column is not formatted as a mysql timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), but is formatted just as a standard American Date (07/09/2014). Is there a way to grab all rows within the next 7 days in my query? I was thinking that it might be possible using DATE_FORMAT, but I have been unable to figure it out.

Comment: mysql str_to_date http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: 1. Format the date column correctly

Comment: @Strawberry This is the ideal, but not the practical solution. There is too much code already referencing the date column in this way. Months of refactoring isn't really an option at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to a date using `str_to_date()`:

```
WHERE str_to_date(`scheduledDate`, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN now() and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

The logic also needs to change.  The above uses `between`, but this may not be the logic your really need because of the extraneous time component on `now()`.  Perhaps this is closer:

```
WHERE str_to_date(`scheduledDate`, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() and DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE scheduledDate >= Date_Add(now(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? You might explain what the OP is doing incorrectly and how/why this would work.